# How to solve undefined symbol for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

I'm trying to compile my class and I get the following result.

```
g++ test.cpp -lconfig++ -stdlib=libstdc++
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "CommandParser::parseCommand(std::string)", referenced from:
      _main in test-8f6e3f.o
  "CommandParser::CommandParser()", referenced from:
      _main in test-8f6e3f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is the class that I'm trying to compile:

```
#include "commandparser.h"

using namespace libconfig;

CommandParser::CommandParser(string configFile){
  this->configFile = configFile;
}


CommandParser::CommandParser(){
  this->configFile = CONFIG_FILE_NAME;
}

string CommandParser::parseCommand(string cmd){
  Config cfg;

  try{
    cfg.readFile(this->configFile.c_str());
  }
  catch (const FileIOException &fi){
    cerr << "I/O error while reading file." << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  catch (const ParseException &pe){
    cerr << "Parse error at " << pe.getFile() << ":" << pe.getLine()
              << " - " << pe.getError() << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  try{
    string path = cfg.lookup(cmd);
    cout << "The path to the script is: " << path << endl;
    return path;
  }
  catch(const SettingNotFoundException &e){
    cerr << "No command with the name '"<<cmd<<"'"<<endl;
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

How can I fix this and get the code to compile? 
I'm running a Mac OSX 10.9.

Comment: did you declare all of these in your .h then include the .h in your main?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm only guessing here, and that guess is that the code you shown is not part of the `test.cpp` file, but is in a separate file. That means your build command

```
$ g++ test.cpp -lconfig++ -stdlib=libstdc++
```

will only build `test.cpp`. It will not automatically add other source files to the compilation process.

You have to explicitly build with *all* relevant source files, like

```
$ g++ test.cpp commandparser.cpp -lconfig++ -stdlib=libstdc++
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it! 
I forgot to add the source files like you said.
Do you happen to know how I can get Eclipse to link all the relevant source files as well? If I compile it manually it seems to work but I still get the error in eclipse.

Comment: @Shookie It's been sometime that I worked with Eclipse, but shouldn't it be enough to add the file in the project?